# Replacing .shtml extension with .php version of the same file

Tags: php, apache, server, cpanel, shtml

I have a whole bunch of .shtml files on my server which are outdated and have been replaced with php versions of the files with updated content. The names of the new php files have been retained eg. buttonClass.shtml has an equivalent file called buttonClass.php in the same directory. 
My server is using CPanel and Apache is there a simple method of redirecting all .shtml files within a certain directory, to a file of the same name but with a .php extension in the same directory?

Comment: Take a look at apaches mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

you could use htaccess to do this. (the file would need to be in the root dir)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.shtml$ $1.php
```

please note that Ive not tested this

Comment: Since the OP has adminstrative access to the apache server it would make more sense to define the rewriting rule in the host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files should only be used as a fallback solution if you do not have access to the host configuration. Reason is that `.htaccess` style files have to be enabled first, open security issues, are notoriously error prone, are hard to debug and _really_ slow the server down.